# Laravel 5.7: A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get sitewide global settings from the database and use those settings in my controllers.

In order to do this I've created a custom **global.php** file under **config** directory.
Defined **key=>value** pairs.
Tried to get values using **DB::table(....)** facade.

But it returns this error:

> **A facade root has not been set**.

I cannot get past beyond this.

**config.php** file as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return [ 

    'image_resize' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('image_resize'),
    'popup' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('popup'),
    'site_on' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('site_on')

];
```

Comment: Why not use the .env file?

Comment: did you enable the facades in the `app.php` file?

Comment: @Adam: because i want to rewrite those settings using my control panel.

Comment: @kuh-chan: Yes i use DB facade in several other controllers of the project.

Comment: That error occurs because in laravel firstly registered configs and then Facades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Config::set('global', [
            'image_resize' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('image_resize'),
            'popup' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('popup'),
            'site_on' => DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->value('site_on')
        ]);
    }
```

Then in controller you can use `config('global.site_on')`

Also you can use one query not three

```
public function register()
{
    $setting = DB::table('settings')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->first(['popup', 'image_resize', 'site_on']);
    Config::set('global', [
        'image_resize' => $setting->image_resize,
        'popup' => $setting->popup,
        'site_on' => $setting->site_on
    ]);
}
```

Or more shortly code is

```
public function register()
{
    $setting = DB::table('settings')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->first(['popup', 'image_resize', 'site_on']);
    Config::set('global', get_object_vars($setting));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davit, i've tried but it gives this error: "Class 'App\Providers\Config' not found"

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` see updated answer

Comment: @megavolkan are you try it ??

Comment: Yes i have, and it works brilliantly. Except short code dosen't work. It throws an error saying 'Constant 'setting' is not defined in get_bject_vars(setting) method'. I've used the long version and it works. Thank you @Davit.

Comment: Try `this Config::set('global', get_object_vars($setting));` it must be `$setting` I forget `$`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after I was fiddling with my app/config.php file. I added some options and accidentally put a semi-colon instead of a comma after it. 
I had:

```
'vapid_public_key'   => env('VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'); <--- offending semi-colon
'vapid_private_key'  => env('VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY'),
```

Changed it to the proper comma and everything works as expected.